# Magento 2.1.4, in Admin panel > Content > Design > Configuration page, no data is showing. I am attaching a screenshot for reference

Tags: magento, magento2, magento2.1

Magento 2.1.4, in the Admin panel > Content > Design > Configuration page, no data is showing.

[image: Screenshot]

Why?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**In the cmd,run the following commands**

1. bin/magento indexer:info
2. bin/magento indexer:status
3. bin/magento indexer:reset design_config_grid
4. bin/magento indexer:reset
5. bin/magento indexer:reindex

**Check for the store view name in the admin dashboard. Set it to Default store view.**

6. bin/magento cache:clean
7. bin/magento cache:flush